# Holding overlapping Schengen visas, may I treat one as an extension without exiting?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, business-travel, visa-expiration

I have got Schengen Visa from Italy (Consulate General of Mumbai) on April 30, 2019. I got Visa from June 8, 2019 - July 6, 2019 with validity of 15 days. I had previous visa from Embassy of Netherlands from June 8, 2018 - June 8, 2019 with validity of 90 days. I have already used 15 days in June 2018, 7 days in Jan 2019 for the Schengen Visa issued by Embassy of Netherlands in June 2018.

I told Consulate General of Mumbai that I'll travel on June 9, 2019 and stay till June 16, 2019, however, my employer is asking me to travel on June 1, 2019 and stay in Switzerland till June 8 and enter Italy on June 9 and stay there till June 22. Now I know in Schengen Visa Code this is allowed, but I am anxious like hell. My company is big on cost cutting and they are saying spending INR 150,000 (EUR 2000) on Return Business Flight is useless as you are allowed to enter on one visa and leave on another visa. I am just scared that they will ask me why I didn't tell this earlier....

I was suppose to travel to Switzerland in end of May and return on June 7, 2019 anyhow, but my employer is asking why I am returning and just travel on June 9, 2019 to Italy as Hotel cost is just INR 15,000 (EUR 200)

Comment: Even if you had told them of your plans, they could only have issued the next visa valid from June 9 as you old visa is valid till June 8.

Comment: Thanks RedBaron, all I am concerned about is one thing, wont they ask why didn't I told them this while making an application and why suddenly changing it! Given now my itinerary is changed I am entering on June 1 and leaving on June 22. All I have is the documents from my employer in India (subsidy of Swiss Pharmaceutical Company in Mumbai) on its letter head

Comment: I'd be more concerned about change of return date from 16 to 22 june rather than the change of departure date from 9 to 1 (You had some other business in a different country which is covered by previous visa). By choosing to depart later, you will be leaving on 15th day (last permitted day). If flight is delayed/cancelled, you will risk overstay. Also the concern you have raised in your comment is wholly different from the question you have posted. Maybe open a new question for that?

Comment: Thanks! I am leaving on 14th day (22nd June) - 9th shall be first day in Italy - 22nd shall be last day when I'll leave for Mumbai